# Jenkinw configuration is removed after restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have ec2 server in aws. I run a docker image of jenkins and setup everything in jenkins (downlaod plugins, make jobs etc.)

But when i restart server or restart docker image, the next time I start jenkins everything is removed, so I have to setup everything from zero.

My question is how can I save my configuration that I do not need to setup everything after restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reason is whenever your container start and stop and you did not specify a place on your host machine where you can save the container volume it will removes once you restart the session

please follow this :

docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins

here /your/home can refer to any of your directory on your host machine.

If I have to run a Jenkins Container

ssh root@192.168.2.13

pwd

/root/home

mkdir Jenkins_vol

cd Jenkins_vol

now run the command :

docker run --name Myjenkins -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /home/Jenkins_vol:/var/jenkins_home Jenkins:latest

after this you can confirm by restart you container it will work well.

Please let me know if there is an issue .
Do follow this docker Jenkins documentation : https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/